Tool to split GoPro MP4 footage into smaller parts for use with iMovie
I recently started some basic editing of my GoPro footage using iMovie on macOS, but quickly ran into some limitations of iMovie i.e. it cannot import MP4 footage greater than around 2GB.
I tried using ffmpeg to split up the MP4, but I think the GoPro metadata in the GoPro TCD, GoPro MET, GoPro SOS streams is tripping up ffmpeg and most of my attempts with it have been failures.
Is there any other small, ideally command-line-based tool, that is known to work with GoPro MP4 footage to split them into smaller MP4s by duration or file size (while being mindful of the keyframes)?
I am aware of Davinci Resolve but I am keen to prove the workflow with iMovie. I am looking for something that has a small footprint, is simple to use, doesn't do a whole lot of things, and is not a full-blown video editor (which would defeat the purpose of using iMovie)

Which specific commands did you use with ffmpeg and how did it fail?

Ah, I see. In theory, you can tell ffmpeg to ignore the GoPro streams with -map -0:2 -map -0:3, in practice it then fails due to corrupted video packet or similar.

The App GoPro Quik from GoPro boasts that it has Premium Editing Tools that allow you to "Play with color and light, trim video length, add stickers, etc ..." Worth a look.

@IconDaemon Besides being rather restricted unless you pay for a subscription, it says "GoPro is announcing the end of life of the GoPro Quik app for macOS, effective at the end of 2024."

@nohillside I had closed the terminal, but the last ffmpeg command attempted was this one ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map 0:v -map 0:a -c copy -segment_time 00:08:00 -f segment -segment_format mp4 output%03d.mp4 and it produced an empty file while barfing out error like (see next comment).

@nohillside - error was "Could not find tag for codec none in stream #2, codec not currently supported in container". It is only one of the various combination of ffmpeg invocations that I tried.

@IconDaemon, I have the app on my phone and it is indeed good for TikToc shorts style videos, but editing them for longer format is quite painful. Also having paid the subscription for my phone, didn't want to pay it for Mac too, but thanks for the suggestion anyway.
